# How to store/read data with a web worker in a cross-origin context differing from the initial domain?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, web-worker

I'm trying to interact with the local storage of a different domain from a given origin.

To give you more clarity, my app is hosted under domain `a.mydomain.net` and I've got a web worker on `c.customdomain.com` which is starting well, but when I attempt to write data from this worker, it persists the data onto `a.mydomain.net` rather than the web worker's domain.

This worker is hosted on the second domain and works fine, but I can't figure out how to store the payload on the remote domain (still in the browser) rather than the initial origin (`a.mydomain.net`)

```js
import { get, set } from 'idb-keyval';


onmessage = (e) => {

    set('hello', e.data)
        .then(() => {
            // @ts-ignore
            postMessage('it persisted data')
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('It failed!', err));
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this and if so, what would be the recommended storage medium?

[image: indexed-db-pic]

Following that same approach, I'd like to be able to change the security origin used when writing the payload into indexed-db, not using localhost:3000 but the worker's origin.

Here's how I load my remote web-worker hosted on a different origin:

```
const workerUrl = 'https://remote-uri.com/workers/main.js';
const workerImportScript = `importScripts(${JSON.stringify(workerUrl)})`
const workerBlobType = {type: 'application/javascript'}

const workerBlob = new Blob([workerImportScript], workerBlobType);
const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob));
```

Comment: "This worker is hosted on the second domain and works fine", I don't believe this point. Please show how you load your worker. Workers need to be same origin. Besides, you do realize the HUGE security risk implied by what you are trying to do? Basically you are trying to read the data of an other website from yours, does that sound like something you'd want to be possible? Do you really want that any website having an ad displayed right here in stackoverflow is able to read all the data stored in any of your social media websites, or from your bank?

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your comment, I've updated my initial post

Comment: So your worker is not hosted on the second domain, it is hosted in your browser's memory and it shares its origin with your own document. (the worker's script is in the Blob). There is just no way to do what you want to do, as I said in my initial comment, that would be an HUGE security/privacy risk.

Comment: @Kaiido The worker's code is hosted remotely, but is started in my browser's memory (so the context is the same as the local domain), that's correct. I wanted to know if there was a way to interact with a different domain via web worker. Apparently I've got one answer and thanks for it.